# Dependency Injection in AWS Lambda function using dotnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am new to Aws Lambda and trying to figure out how to use Dependency Injection into Aws Lambda using .net core 2.1.

I am trying to inject `IHttpClientFactory`, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

I am calling below method in the constructor of the lambda function class:

```
  private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("client", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someurl");
        });

       return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Is this correct?

Also, after it returns `IServiceProvider`, how do I use it in any class where I need to call `IHttpClientFactory`?

(I have gone through some related articles, but I am still unclear to use the output from `ConfigureServices()` method when called in the constructor?)

Thanks.

Example of usage for DI:

```
public class Function
{
   private readonly ITestClass _test;
   public Function()
    {
       ConfigureServices();
    }

    public async Task Handler(ILambdaContext context)
    {
       _test.Run(); //Run method from TestClass that implements ITestClass and calls IHttpClientFactory to make call to an API

      //return something
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("client", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someurl");
        });
       serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITestClass, TestClass>();
       serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); //is it needed??
    }
}
```

Comment: So far what you have is usable. As for your other questions you would need to show some code that helps demonstrate what it is you are trying to so. Show an example function with the included snippet above.

Answer (score 6):

Assign the service provider as the DI container and use it in your functions

*Function.cs*

```
public class Function {

    public static Func<IServiceProvider> ConfigureServices = () => {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("client", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someurl");
        });
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITestClass, TestClass>();
        return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    };

    static IServiceProvider services;
    static Function() {
        services = ConfigureServices();
    }


    public async Task Handler(ILambdaContext context) {
        ITestClass test = services.GetService<ITestClass>();
        await test.RunAsync(); 

        //...
    }
}
```

Using a static constructor for a one time call to configure your services and build the service container.

Comment: thanks. can Handler() be unit tested by mocking ITestClass?

Comment: You would need to make `ConfigureServices` public and overridable by converting it to a `Func<IServiceProvider>` so that it can be replaced when testing

Comment: @Nkosi internal should be fine.

Comment: @coolio you dont need to test handle in truth. Just test your ITestClass implemenation, and test your Services implementation.  If youre testing handle youre really testing AWS implementation at that point.

Comment: This is a bad example. If ITestClass has IHttpClientFactory dependency, then if there will be concurrent executions for the lambda it will have SocketException because IHttpClientFactory should be created as a singleton for AWS Lambda Execution Context. So the ITestClass test = services.GetService<ITestClass>(); should be placed inside Function() constructor for this purposes.